# Detectando números coma flotante en un string con Python

Tags: python, regex

Estoy escribiendo un pequeño programa en Python 3.x para detectar números de coma flotante dados en una cadena (string). Se tienen **2 inputs**, el primero es **"T" un número entero que define la cantidad de strings** que serán introducidas en el siguiente input (N).

**Tarea:** detectar en esos strings cuáles son números de coma flotante (floats) válidos. Los números podrán tener el siguiente formato:

✔+4.50

✔-1.0

✔.5

✔-.7

✔+.4

Ejemplos no válidos:

✖ -+4.5

✖ 12.

✖ 4

✖ 4.0O0

Podrán comenzar con: "+", "-" o "."

El siguiente código sólo genera respuesta para las dos primeras cadenas (Sólo hasta T = 2) :(

---

```
import re
pattern= r'[+|-]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+'

T = input().strip()

N = str(input()).strip() 

i = 1

for i in range(int(T)):
    if re.fullmatch(pattern, N): 
        print("True")
        i += 1
    else: 
        print("False") 
        i += 1
```

Cualquier ayuda estaré agradecido!

Comment: Lo primero que veo es que estás mezclando la variable `i`. La usas como contador pero también como variable de tu bucle `for`.

Comment: ¿No se debería llamar a `input()` dentro del for?

Answer (score 2):

Resuelto! Era un simple detalle... :)

Sólo pasar "N = str(input()).strip() " dentro del loop for...

```
import re
pattern= r'[+|-]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+'
T = input().strip()

i = 1

for i in range(int(T)):
    N = str(input()).strip() 
    if re.fullmatch(pattern, N): 
        print("True")
        i += 1
    else: 
        print("False") 
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay alternativas al uso de expresiones regulares.

Te propongo `eval()`. Esta función toma un string conteniendo una expresión Python válida, la evalua y retorna un objeto del tipo correspondiente. Así, si la expresión evalua a un `int`, produce un objeto `int` de vuelta:

```
>>>>x=eval("1+3")
>>>>x
4
>>>>type(x)
<class 'int'>
```

Si la expresión es interpretable como `float`, retorna un `float`

```
>>>>x=eval("+45.4")
>>>>x
45.4
>>>>type(x)
<class 'float'>
```

Si la expresión es inválida o hay cualquier problema, `eval` genera una excepción.

La ventaja de usar `eval` es que si reconoce algo como `float`, es seguro que es realmente un `float`. Igualmente, si no lo reconoce como `float`, es totalmente seguro que no es un `float`.

Pero no es aconsejable usar `eval`, por los riesgos de seguridad. En su lugar usaremos `ast.literal_eval`, que sólo acepta un conjunto reducido de expresiones (pero suficientes para este caso).

**Comprobación**

Este programa prueba el funcionamiento de `ast.literal_eval` para reconocer `float`.

```
import ast

while True:
    str_input = input("Ingrese un número en punto flotante: ")
    try:
        a = ast.literal_eval(str_input)
    except:
        a = None
    if type(a) is not float:
        print("  *** No valido ***")
```

produce

```
Ingrese un número en punto flotante: 45
  *** No valido ***
Ingrese un número en punto flotante: 45.0
Ingrese un número en punto flotante: +45.0
Ingrese un número en punto flotante: uno
  *** No valido ***
Ingrese un número en punto flotante: uno dos mil
  *** No valido ***
Ingrese un número en punto flotante: 45i
  *** No valido ***
Ingrese un número en punto flotante:
```